# How to get records from one table which are not in another table's fields (3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to get all records from table `Binaryfile` where `Binaryfile.id` is **not in** `Image.fullimage_id` **and not in** `Image.preview_id` **and not in** `Image.thumbnail_id`

I tried with the following, but I get all records from `Binaryfile` which are not in `Image.fullimage_id` **or not in** `Image.preview_id` **or not in** `Image.thumbnail_id`

```
binaryfiles = Binaryfile.where('id NOT IN (?)', [Image.select("fullimage_id"), Image.select("preview_id"), Image.select("thumbnail_id")])
```

How can I change the condition from `or` to `and`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Binaryfile.where.not(id: Image.pluck(:fullimage_id, :preview_id, :thumbnail_id).flatten)
```